# Getting InvalidFilterException when querying a date range using Azure CosmosDb Table API

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I'm trying to get a set of results with timestamp within a given date range from a CosmosDb using the Table API.

This is how I'm constructing my query:

```
        var from = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual,
            new DateTimeOffset(2018, 2, 15, 15, 2, 45, TimeSpan.Zero));

        var to = TableQuery.GenerateFilterConditionForDate("Timestamp", QueryComparisons.LessThan,
            new DateTimeOffset(2018, 2, 15, 15, 3, 45, TimeSpan.Zero));

        return new TableQuery<Audit>()
            .Where(
                TableQuery.CombineFilters(from, TableOperators.And, to));
```

However, when I run this query I get the following exception of type `InvalidFilterException`:

> ODataException: Unrecognized 'Edm.String' literal
>   'datetime'2018-02-15T15:02:45.0000000Z'' at '14' in '(Timestamp ge
>   datetime'2018-02-15T15:02:45.0000000Z') and (Timestamp ge
>   datetime'2018-02-15T15:03:45.0000000Z')'.

Can anyone help me understand what this means? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone help me understand what this means? Am I doing something wrong?

I also can reproduce this with [Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table version](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table/1.0.0) 1.0.0 on my side.

If I update the version of Microsoft.Azure.CosmosDB.Table version to 1.1.0 then no exception, the filter result count always equals 0.

It seems that filtering with Timestamp is not supported now. You also could give your [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db) to Azure team.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate you taking the time. I can confirm that I was using version 1.0.0. I will indeed provide the feedback. I ended up having to switch my solution to use the Cosmos SQL API which does support filtering by DateTime field.

Comment: Exactly what we did :)

Comment: Is this still the case??